# KDE's Kate: How to setup indentation in a configuration file?

Tags: xml, syntax-highlighting, kate

I have written an XML file containing syntax highlighting for a yet unsupported language. The indentation convention of this language is:

- First indentation level: 4 spaces
- Second level: 1 tab
- Third level: 1 tab + 4 spaces
- Fourth level: 2 tabs
- Fifth level : 2 tabs + 4 spaces
- etc.

where every tabs are 8 spaces wide.

I know I can set kate to respect that indentation convention through the GUI: `Configure --> Editor Component --> Editing --> Indentation --> Tabulators and Spaces` but I am wondering if I could add that information in the XML file directly, so users would just have a single file to copy in `~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax/`.

So my question is, can the indentation convention be added to the XML syntax highlighting file?

Thanks

Using Kate 3.14.1 on KDE 4.14.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Syntax XML files are not capable to set that properties.
You may set that properties using [modelines](https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/config-variables.html) or [`.kateconfig`](http://kate-editor.org/2006/02/09/kateconfig-files/) file.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Thanks for the clarification. Do you know if I can place the modelines in a config file somewhere? Even [the doc](https://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/config-variables.html) is not clear as to where to put this (f.e. where is the "global configuration"?).

Comment: `.kateconfig` supposed to be "near" your document/project. best place is a top source tree root. but to override smth one may put it deeper in a directory layout of your project.

Comment: I can manage putting a `.kateconfig` file in my own project directories, but other devs will not do this step. I am looking for a way for them to set this once and forget it, ideally a simple file to place somewhere, similar to the syntax XML file...

Comment: 0) put that file to version control, so other devs will get it… or
1) share your `$HOME/.kde4/share/config/kate*` files to your devs… or 2) implement this feature and send a patch to [KDE reviewboard](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org) -- there is no other ways nowadays.